# ArcGIS Pro - Raster Calculator Percentiles - conditional

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I want to 'cap' the values of a raster if it exceeds the percentile value. For example if the 95th percentile value of the raster was 10000, then anything at or above that value would be assigned a value of 10000.
I have a manual way of doing this in Raster Calculator, but this involves me finding the percentile value beforehand:

```
Con( "Extract_h1_d1">10000,10000, "Extract_h1_d1")
```

Is there a way to include the percentile within Raster Calculator function itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in model builder using the Calculate Value tool to run a tiny piece of python. Model is just this:

[image: Model]

Calculate Value tool is set up as it:

[image: Calculate Value tool]

The code in code block is this:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np
def per95(raster):
    npArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster)
    p = np.percentile(npArray, 95)
    return p
```

The CON tool is set up as is:

[image: CON tool]

*Note output of Calculate Value tool is a precondition to CON tool.*

Comment: Is there a way to set the 'Input true raster or constant value' equal to the Value calculated in the python code?

Comment: Just use [inline variable substitution](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/inline-variable-substitution.htm).